# atob() exception in Safari, but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

Any idea why the same base64 string passed to atob() would work in Chrome but not Safari?

From the console, I called `atob(data)` for the same base64 data string

[image: atob(data) throws exception in Safari]

Answer (score 0):

On my case, Chrome's `atob()` allows encoded string to including '\n', Firefox does and Safari does not.

https://github.com/buunguyen/octotree/pull/149